# php uploaded video is not seek forward on chrome, (seekbar not working)

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, video, seek

So i have a **simple php script** which uploads the video file to the server then after the upload when i load that video on a video page the **seek bar of the video element is not working** on chrome browser. it works fine on firefox but does not work on chrome. i am not able to seek forward or backward the video.... all videos on the other websites works fine.. so i guess its not the browser issue..
i used two php version 7.4 and 5.6 but got no luck finding a problem

Comment: It is probably the browser compatibility issue...as you just said "works fine on firefox"..What format is the video?

Comment: does it work when the video has had time to fully load? does it work if you open just the direct video URL?

Comment: it is same the case with every video type
and it doesn't load fully

Comment: also it does this with the uploaded videos only.... if i copy a video file in the project it works fine for the copies video but does not work with uploaded videos

Comment: i used this code  
axios.get('<?php echo $link ?>',{
        responseType : 'blob'
      }).then((resp)=>{
      vid =  URL.createObjectURL(resp.data)
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
            var source = document.createElement('source');   
            source.setAttribute('src', vid);
            video.appendChild(source);
            video.play();
      }).catch((e)=>{}) to load full video but it works but it takes minutes to download the full video

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is something with the headers...chrome is not loading the video url pointing directly towards the video resource... i found  vdeo streaming library for that with streams the video which works perfectly